# Getting attributes from current controller in owin middleware

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, self-hosting, attributerouting

Driving me a bit mad so hopefully someone can help me.

Using WebAPI I can do something like this

```
public class AuthenticationMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage>SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            var controllerSelector = new DefaultHttpControllerSelector(config);
            var descriptor = controllerSelector.SelectController(request);

            var atts = descriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IgnoreValidationAttribute>();
```

This gets me my attribute and I'm happy and smiley and all is good.

But

Using attribute routing, I believe is the problem, using the above code or replacing

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
```

with

```
var config = request.GetConfiguration();
```

I get null exceptions and I'm less happy and smiley. Can some wonderful person give me some pointers to get around this as I'm stumped.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it in an ASP MVC application, so I think there should be a similar way to access the descriptor from the request in Web API

```
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    private bool HasAttribute<T>()
    {
        var skip = false;
        try
        {
            var routeDataList = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Values.First() as IList<System.Web.Routing.RouteData>;
            var routeData = routeDataList.First() as System.Web.Routing.RouteData;
            var actionDescriptorList = routeData.DataTokens.Values.First() as IList<object>;
            var reflectedActionDescriptor = actionDescriptorList.First() as ReflectedActionDescriptor;
            skip = reflectedActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false)
                                                .Any();
        }
        catch
        {
            //can't get the attributes; skip should be false
        }
        return skip;
    }
```